# My state value should be re-rendering the whole component and that should put my other state value to default again but it's not happening

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, components, state

```
import React from "react"


export default function Components() {
    const PI = 3.14
     
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState("")
    const [inputvalue, setInputvalue] = React.useState(0)

    function calculation() { 
        const originalvalue = PI * inputvalue * inputvalue

        setValue(`${originalvalue} cm^2`)
        console.log(value)
    }
    
    function getInput (event) {
        setInputvalue(event.target.value)
        
    }   

    console.log("main")

    return (
        <div className="output">
            <h4>Enter the r of the circle below in cm</h4>
           
           <input onChange={getInput} type="number"  name="input"/>

           <button onClick = {calculation}> Show Area</button>

           <p>Area of the circle is : {value}</p>
        </div>

    )
}
```

So whenever I input a number my component is re-rendering(I checked it with a console log) but my output value which is a state value (Area of the circle is : {value}) still stays on the page. Instead When the component re-renders, it needs to be assigned as "" again. But it's not happening and my code is working fine. I just wanna understand how is this possible

Comment: I don't understand completely your problem. I tried your code and it works fine. Do you want to know why the `console.log` doesn't update immediately while the `value` in the render does?

Comment: I was taught that when my state value is updated it will re-run my whole code and set all the state values back to default again. Am I missing something here? when my inputvalue is updated and my component re-renders it will re-run " const [value, setValue] = React.useState("") " code right? Shouldn't that change the output value in the page when displaying? But it's not changing it doesn't matter how many times I trigger an onChange in input box. That's being my Question. So when I'm inputting numbers my output value should dissapear from the page right? instead why does it stays still

Comment: You were taught wrong. If you need to reset your state you have to do that manually in the code.

Comment: Okay so I guess as I put my setter function of "value" inside an onclick function it won't update the state value as long as I don't click the button even if it re-renders the whole component. Is that right? Ty anyways for pointing out my misunderstanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getInput` is updating `inputvalue`, not `value`.

To get your input element's onChange handler to update the UI content, `getInput` needs to be something more like:

```
function getInput (event) {
    setValue(event.target.value)
}
```

Comment: I get it but when my inputvalue is updated and my component re-renders it will re run " const [value, setValue] = React.useState("") " code right? Shouldn't that change the output value in the page when displaying? But it's not changing it doesn't matter how many times I trigger an onChange in input box. That's being my Question. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: State persists between renders, that's the entire purpose of state variables. So no, the value of `value` will be unchanged because you haven't called setValue at all